# ¿Como marcar una casilla de un DataGridView cuando es marcada?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

Con el fin de facilitarle al usuario determinar que casillas selecciono en un `datagridview`, deseo cambiarle el color a la casilla seleccionada (la cual seria modificada al dispararse el evento `CellContentClick`), el problema es que cuando queria determinar si fue checkeada, simplemente invertia el valor del `check` y listo, pero esto no me funciona si lo que deseo es pintar una casilla, se selecciona, pero esta no se pinta hasta que el usuario seleccione otra casilla cualquiera en el `datagridview`. Probe muchas formas de solucionarlo y ninguna funciono:

1. Eventos que se ejecuten despues del `evento` (como el `MouseUp`).
2. Metodos como `Update()` y `Refresh()`.
3. El metodo `EndEdit()`.
4. Cambiarle la propiedad `Visible` despues del `evento` para ver si asi se actualizaba correctamente la casilla.
5. Probe seleccionar otra casilla despues del evento.
6. Soluciones de foros y blogs. Un ejemplo: http://ltuttini.blogspot.com/2010/04/datagridview-uso-del-checkbox.html

El codigo que tengo dentro del `evento` es el siguiente:

```
    private void DgvDatosReservas_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView DetectarTipoCasilla = (DataGridView)sender;

        if (DetectarTipoCasilla.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn && e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            // invierto el estado del check seleccionado debido a que no se actualiza en el momento de marcarlo.
            if (dgvDatosReservas.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[(int)ENumColDGVDatosReservas.Seleccionar].Value != null)
            {
                if (!(bool)dgvDatosReservas.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[(int)ENumColDGVDatosReservas.Seleccionar].Value)
                {
                    dgvDatosReservas.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[(int)ENumColDGVDatosReservas.Seleccionar].Style.BackColor = ClsColores.Azul;
                }
                else
                {
                    dgvDatosReservas.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[(int)ENumColDGVDatosReservas.Seleccionar].Style.BackColor = ClsColores.GrisOscuroFondo;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

En la siguiente foto muestro como me queda el `control`, en donde se puede ver que la ultima casilla que seleccione no se esta pintando, ya que esta esperando que seleccione otra casilla del `datagridview`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una solucion (que no se si seria valida ya que el `datagridview` podria seguir esperando la seleccion de una casilla para editarse) podria ser indicar un `metodo` que se ejecute un poco despues de el `evento` mostrado anteriormente, pintando las casillas que esten seleccionadas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontre la solucion al problema y comparto la respuesta por si alguien se encuentra con el mismo problema:

```
    private void DgvDatosReservas_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView DetectarTipoCasilla = (DataGridView)sender;

    if (DetectarTipoCasilla.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn && e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        // invierto el estado del check seleccionado debido a que no se actualiza en el momento de marcarlo.
        if (dgvDatosReservas.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[(int)ENumColDGVDatosReservas.Seleccionar].Value != null)
        {
            if (!(bool)dgvDatosReservas.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[(int)ENumColDGVDatosReservas.Seleccionar].Value)
            {
                dgvDatosReservas.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[(int)ENumColDGVDatosReservas.Seleccionar].Style.BackColor = ClsColores.Azul;
            }
            else
            {
                dgvDatosReservas.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[(int)ENumColDGVDatosReservas.Seleccionar].Style.BackColor = ClsColores.GrisOscuroFondo;
            }
        }

        // Metodo que soluciono el problema
        dgvDatosReservas.ClearSelection();
    }
}
```

No estoy completamente seguro del porque, lo probe ya que se solucionaba al darle foco a otra celda del `DataGridView`, por lo que intuyo que al limpiar la lista de seleccion, actualiza las celdas tal y como necesitaba. Si se selecciona la misma casilla (para quitarle la seleccion), no funciona el invertir el valor booleano de la casilla del `check`, por lo que recomiendo guardar el valor de esa posicion de fila y columna, para de esta forma deterinar si selecciono la misma y asi entre a la linea del else y le saque el color a la casilla (igual puede fallar si el usuario hace click repetidas veces rapido en la casilla o si selecciona la misma 2 veces seguidas, es muy raro el comportamiento de esta funcion del control).
Si alguien sabe explicarlo en mas detalle, su respuesta es bienvenida.